# Argument type 'xxx' does not conform to expected type '_FormatSpecifiable'

Tags: swift, swiftui

While I was playing around with SwiftUI, I ran into two unexpected errors:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "hello" }
}

class MyClass: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "hi" }
}

let a = MyStruct()
let b = MyClass()
let s1 = "\(a)"        // hello
let s2 = "\(b)"        // hi

// ❌ Argument type 'MyStruct' does not conform to
//    expected type '_FormatSpecifiable'
let text1 = Text("\(a)")

// ❌ Cannot convert value of type 'MyClass' to
//    expected argument type 'String'
let text2 = Text("\(b)")

let n = 1

// ✅ this one is OK, why?
let text3 = Text("\(n)")
```

Does anyone know what these errors mean? And why the first two `Text`s don't work but the last one is OK? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

Conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` allows you to customise the `description` which can later be accessed with `String(describing:)`:

```
let a = MyStruct()
let text = String(describing: a)
```

However, by calling:

```
let text1 = Text("\(a)")
```

you're effectively calling this constructor:

```
public init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil)
```

Note that `"\(a)"` is not a `String` - it's a `LocalizedStringKey`.

#### Error

> Argument type 'MyStruct' does not conform to expected type
> '_FormatSpecifiable'

`LocalizedStringKey` already conforms to `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` but its inner struct (`StringInterpolation`) doesn't have methods that accept parameters of type `MyStruct`.

See

```
public mutating func appendInterpolation<T>(_ value: T) where T : SwiftUI._FormatSpecifiable
```

in the implementation of `LocalizedStringKey`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@frozen public struct LocalizedStringKey : Swift.Equatable, Swift.ExpressibleByStringInterpolation {
  ...
  public struct StringInterpolation : Swift.StringInterpolationProtocol {
    public init(literalCapacity: Swift.Int, interpolationCount: Swift.Int)
    public mutating func appendLiteral(_ literal: Swift.String)
    public mutating func appendInterpolation(_ string: Swift.String)
    public mutating func appendInterpolation<Subject>(_ subject: Subject, formatter: Foundation.Formatter? = nil) where Subject : Foundation.ReferenceConvertible
    public mutating func appendInterpolation<Subject>(_ subject: Subject, formatter: Foundation.Formatter? = nil) where Subject : ObjectiveC.NSObject
    public mutating func appendInterpolation<T>(_ value: T) where T : SwiftUI._FormatSpecifiable
    public mutating func appendInterpolation<T>(_ value: T, specifier: Swift.String) where T : SwiftUI._FormatSpecifiable
    @available(iOS 14.0, OSX 11.0, tvOS 14.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
    public mutating func appendInterpolation(_ text: SwiftUI.Text)
    public typealias StringLiteralType = Swift.String
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Solution

You need to manually create an extension to accept `MyStruct` parameters:

```
extension LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: MyStruct) {
        appendInterpolation(String(describing: value))
    }
}
```

Now you can just call:

```
let text1 = Text("\(a)")
```

---

Alternatively you can use a different init to make sure you're passing a `String` and not a `LocalizedStringKey`:

```
let text1 = Text(verbatim: "\(a)")
```

---

Useful links:

- [How to use custom string interpolation in Swift 5](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/163/how-to-use-custom-string-interpolation-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This means that `Text` does not have constructor matching those cases, use instead

```
let text1 = Text(String("\(a)"))
let text2 = Text(String("\(b)"))
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: but I'm so confused, aren't `"\(a)"` and `"\(b)"` already `String`s ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
let text1 = Text("\(a)")
```

Do:

```
let text1 = Text(a.description)
```

Do the same for the other one.